# Applying all transform to a scaled rig

Tags: rigging, transform-orientation

Hi I’m new to blender and I had scaled a rigged character using the armature but when I try to apply all transforms to the rig, the character deforms to something weird. How do i fix this without having to redo the rig and weight paints?

Comment: If your rig uses no constraints or drivers, unparent mesh with keep transform, *then* apply scale on both armature and mesh, then reparent mesh to armature.  Not guaranteed in presence of constraints/drivers; depends on specifics of those.

Comment: The rig doesn’t use any constraints or drivers. So that means i will have to redo the weight paints?

Comment: No, you won't have to redo any weighting.

Comment: I’ve tried, i hit Alt+P > unparent and keep transformation. Then applied scale of mesh and later applied scale of Rig but it still deforms

Comment: I would have to see a file to tell you anything more.

Comment: The thing is that i have a rigged character that doesn’t have a face rig and so i made a face rig and i want to join the two but the problem is that I already scaled the rig to a smaller size because it was too big, so when i try to join the two rigs together the deformation bones of the face rig are deforming but when i tried to join the two rigs before i scaled the body rig, the deformation bones don’t deform. I don’t know if that makes sense. How do i share the file?

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to edit the question (and title) to provide all of that detail-- and even more.  It would be nice if you could separate the scaling issues, because then you could ask a clean "Why do my bones no longer deform the mesh after joining these two armatures?"  A good place to host files for Blender SE is at https://blend-exchange.com/ .